# User table not having root user

Tags: mysql, join, select

I am trying to reset password for `root` user and I have successfully executed below commands

```
service mysql stop
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
mysql -u root
```

Now, when I look for `root` within `user` table, I get a `empty set`

```
mysql> select * from user where User regexp 'root';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

How it is possible that there is no `root` account and I am still able to login as `mysql -u root`

What command to use to update `root` password?

I am using MySQL Version 5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view the list of accounts in MySQL use this query :

`SELECT User FROM mysql.user;`

Also to reset the password for root user visit the official documentation of MySQL 5.6 as the command varies for different operating systems -

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html